# Farbangabe für Pfeffersoße

Tags: grammar

Wie bezeichnet man eine Soße die grünen Pfeffer enthält?

Die Lösung unserer Kantine heute Mittag war "grüne Pfeffersoße" bzw. "... mit grüner Pfeffersoße", was ich aber für falsch halte da die Soße an sich ja nicht grün war, sondern nur der enthaltene Pfeffer.

Comment: Wieso nicht einfach Sosse mit grünem Pfeffer?

Comment: @RoflcoptrException Ich frage mich halt ob es ein derart kurzes Konstrukt gibt das nicht das obige Problem hat. Der Auslöser dieser heutigen Stilblüte ist vermutlich extremer Platzmangel gewesen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lol, coole Frage!

Ich vermute einerseits, dass hier die Sprache an ihre Grenzen stößt, weil zufällig die Hauptgeschmackszutat eine bestimmte Farbe hat, die als Adjektiv auch Teil ihres Namens ist - die Sauce selbst allerdings diese Farbe nicht aufweist - einfache Antwort: da kann man nichts machen. Sprache ist nicht immer logisch.

Andererseits ist das Problem wohl nicht so wahnsinnig groß, da keine Verwechslungsgefahr besteht: Eine "Pfeffersoße" kann sinnvollerweise nur dann "grün" sein/heißen, wenn es sich um eine Sauce aus/mit grünem Pfeffer handelt. Andernfalls wäre es wohl eine "Kräutersauce" oder so.

---

Note for English native speakers: "Grüner Pfeffer" refers to unripe Peppercorns and is not at all related to green peppers. So this is *not* about a "green pepper sauce" you might be familiar with... :) In Germany, "Pfeffersoße" is usually a cream base with black or most often green peppercorns. The sauce is therefore sort of beige, not green.

Answer (score 6):

Von einem rein syntaktischen (oder grammatikalischen) Gesichtspunkt wäre

> Rindssteak mit Grüner-Pfeffer-Soße

wohl die Variante, die den Regeln entspricht und auch nicht zweideutig ist.

Allerdings lässt sich darüber streiten, ob es auch stilistisch richtig ist. Glaubt man den Google-Suchergebnissen, tendert das gemeine Internetvolk zu *grüne Pfeffersauce*, aber es gibt auch einzelne [Gegenbeispiele](http://www.onlyfood.de/?p=3390).

Answer (score 2):

Du hast Recht, die Bezeichnung ist überhaupt nicht stimmig. Ich könnte mich ja sehr für

> Grünpfeffersauce

erwärmen, analog zu Weißkrautsalat.

Comment: +1 Interessant ... auf diese Idee, wie auch auf das Gegenbeispiel von @splattne (+1), wäre ich nicht gekommen ...